# Identify vintage bicycle brand

Tags: frames, vintage, build

I don't know much about bicycles but I came across one that I want to offer to my nephew since he is into vintage race bikes. I would like to know the original brand of the bicycle/frame since I want to replicate it with the right decals. I was told the frame tubes are Reynolds 531 and from the equipment (Mafac, Simplex, Belleri) I assume the bicycle is probably French from the 70s after several searches enter image description here. Thank you in advance for your help.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: It's a nice looking bike! The better French bikes from that era usually Vitus tubing for frames, the better Italian frames usually used Columbus, and the British and U.S. bicycles generally used Reynolds 531 tubing. This bike has been repainted. Reynolds stickers can be purchased or made. The sticker is not a reliable indicator for what the frame is made of. Parts are interchangeable and are not a reliable indicator for country of origin, date of manufacture or manufacturer. If there were some unique characteristic of the frame - dropouts, lugs, construction - we might get a match

Comment: The threading of the bottom bracket may be an indicator for French, Italian or British origin, although not to be taken for an absolute truth.

Comment: If a conclusive answer doesn't turn up, then avoid guessing.  Instead leave it bare, exactly as-is, or if you must dress it with decals, get your nephew's name as a water-transfer decal and use that on the downtube. I'd appreciate the personal touch.

Comment: Late 1970s, but fairly generic for that era.

Comment: It would be great if you could post details such as the BB threading, the brand of dropouts, and the seatpost size. The seatpost in particular is a good indication of the quality of the tubing. You might also consider posting in the classic and vintage forum on bikeforums.net. There are many vintage bike experts there who can identify frames based on lug patterns and tubing.

Answer (score 1):

Not particularly fine lugwork. Look like Prugnat lugs, but not S4s. Fork crown isn't too finely filed either. Can't tell the brand of ends from the shots. Straight brake bridge with no tangs at the stays. Can't see BB very well at all. Nor chainstay bridge. Is Campag brazeon cable guides? Can't see. Are forks replacements? Does the fork raking look like it's cheaply done? Match the quality of the lugwork? Fork ends match the stay ends? What else could narrow down its country of origin?

Comment: Might most of this be better as a comment?  There's just the lugs info, and the rest is all requests for clarifications.